# Update multiple rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have columns in MySQL table -> **id, source, title, description, link** and i have big **PHP** array with more than **1000** elements inside containing information wich i need to insert/update into database.
I don't need to use PHP json_encode/decode functions and save info in json format

I tried to insert/update rows using while/for loop but it seems inefficient not a good practice at all

**ERROR:** Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (id,source,title,description,link) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

i = 0;
$count = (int)count($arr);

while(i < $count){

    $stmt = $cn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("issss",
        $arr["id"][$i],
        $arr["source"][$i],
        $arr["title"][$i],
        $arr["description"][$i],
        $arr["link"][$i]
    );
    $stmt->execute();

    ++$i;
}
```

Question: Is it possible to insert/update multiple rows once? and if yes how? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: @Alex No. I do not need to use loops no matter it is foreach for or while loop

Comment: You could write all `values` as CSV, then bind them all. With this approach `$stmt = $cn->prepare($query);` should be outside the loop

Comment: Something like `$query = "INSERT INTO table (id,source,title,description,link) VALUES ("; $query .= implode(',', array_fill(0, count($arr), '(?,?,?,?,?)')) . ')';` for the former approach, will then need to map the bindings which might be hard with mysqli

Comment: I would find out the maximum number of queries the system is able to "eat" per time and sliced the array into pieces and would execute these pieces one by one.